# type conversion error in ignition on running diagnostic

Tags: c#, opc

[image]

The datatypes are UDTs. When I use Tag Editor Data Type parameters to create tagpath it throws the error. However when I directly update the tagpath in OPC window the reads are fine. I can read the value getting updated in the tag window.
Its a custom server built using OPC UA C# stack
[image]